# new session id creator not work when use SSL

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, ssl, https

I want before or after each login to each user Give a new Session ID. I use Asp.net  and IIS 8.0 and windows 2012 server.

I used this method

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Session["userid"] = txt_user_name.Text;
        if (Session["userid"] != null && Session["AuthToken"] != null && Request.Cookies["AuthToken"] != null)
        {
            if (!Session["AuthToken"].ToString().Equals(Request.Cookies["AuthToken"].Value))
            {
                lbl_message.Text = "NOT LOGIN";
            }
        }
        if (txtInput.Text == "")
        {
            CreateSesstion_Click(sender, e);  // This method Generate new Session Id

        }
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
             Captcha();

        }

}

 protected void CreateSesstion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SessionIDManager manager = new SessionIDManager();

    string newID = manager.CreateSessionID(Context);
    bool redirected = false;
    bool isAdded = false;
    manager.SaveSessionID(Context, newID, out redirected, out isAdded);
    HttpContext.Current.Session["x"] = 123;

}
```

This method works fine before publishing it, but after publishing when the site runs with HTTPS, it fails and does not recognize the new Session ID. And makes a mistake.
If it's open without SSL, it works fine

Please help me

Thankful

Comment: The issue is with the IIS server.  The user account is on the client machine and not the IIS,  Make sure the session is coming from the client machine and not server.  The clients do not have read/write permission on the IIS server.

Comment: @jdweng -  In the IIS settings section Session State Model Settings Selected in process option. and section cookie settings selected mode : use cookies and name : asp.net_sessionid and Time-out : 20. In the end section, the 'use hosting identity for impersonation' option is selected

Comment: The user does not have permission to write to the IIS settings.  If you want to save info you have to create a database (could be a file) that the user has access.  Either on the Client PC or a DataBase like SQL Server.  When a user connects to a IIS server the credentials are set to a GUEST account which has very little privileges on the IIS.